# Angular 2 Animation Callback .done, setting properties?

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

Let's say we have:
`<li *ngFor="let item of items" [@myTrigger]='state' (@myTrigger.start)="animStart($event)" (@myTrigger.done)="animDone($event)">{{ item }}</li>`

And method animDone:

```
animDetails: string;

animDone(event:any) {
    console.log('Ended!');
    this.animDetails = 'I am done!';
}
```

In the view I have `{{ animDetails }}`

What's strange is while console.log('Ended!') fires appropriately, animDetails does not.

The first animation, nothing gets changed.  The second animation (initiated by a click of a button), "I am done!" fires immediately, on start, as opposed to .done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK animations run outside Angulars zone for performance reasons.

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

animDetails: string;

animDone(event:any) {
    console.log('Ended!');
    this.animDetails = 'I am done!';
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

There was an issue about to run animation callbacks inside Angulars zone. I assume it was fixed already but your question seems to indicate otherwise, except when you're not using the latest Angular2 version.

Comment: Ah!  I'm using the Angular 2 quickstart for this particular example.  Could that be why?  By the way, I see your name *everywhere* in Angular 2.  Great job!

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean with "quickstart"? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html? It seems to be using the latest version. The issue was fixed 10 days ago. It might not be included in the latest release. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11881